# Writing the week number in the name of a file in a batch File

Tags: batch-file, week-number

I want to include the number of the previous week at the end of the name of the file when copying a file to a different folder with a scrip in a batch file.

I'm trying the following>

```
echo f | xcopy /f /y "\\Mypath\MyFile.xlsb" "\\Mypath\MyFile WK"%WEEK%".xlsb"
```

But the result I'm getting is
\Mypath\MyFile WK.xlsb

Desire result is \Mypath\MyFile WK12.xlsb

Thank you so much

Comment: Is this piece of put in a brackets? like inside `for` or `if`?

Comment: I edited to be more clear

Comment: Related: [ISO week number in CMD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39374549/iso-week-number-in-cmd)

Comment: remove the quotes around `%week%`. Also: is `%week%` already defined, or is your question about "how to calculate the week"?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best answer but for those who need to get the week, this is the way I was able to finally get the week and accomplish what I needed.

```
   WIN32_LOCALTIME GET /FORMAT:LIST') DO @(SET %%a>NUL)
   SET /A a=(14-%Month%)/12,y=%Year%-a,IsoWeek=(%Day%+(153*(%Month%+12*a-3)+2)/5+365*y+y/4)/7-(365*%Year%+(%Year%+3)/4)/7+9

   echo f | xcopy /f /y "\\Mypath\MyFile.xlsb" "\\Mypath\MyFile WK"%IsoWeek%".xlsb"
```